# Horizontal android:animateLayoutChanges="true" Animation not smooth

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-layout-weight, android-layoutparams

I have a layout that animate as below

[image]

The `txt_billion` is shown dynamically, with `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` (Layout code below).

Notice the `Hundred` is jumping (actually all are jumping, but the `Hundred` is just more obvious). How to prevent the text from jumping?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#9f9"
        android:text="Hundreds" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#f9f"
        android:text="Thousands" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#0ff"
        android:text="Millions" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_billion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#ff0"
        android:text="Billions" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You could get the code from https://github.com/elye/issue_horizontal_layout_animate to test out

Comment: on which device? vhich Android version? is the hardware Acceleration enabled?

Comment: Any device. I tried on Android Emulator of Nexus 5, Nougat

Comment: Emulator is not a device. Try on the device first. It should differ a lot.

Comment: It happens on actual device as well. So I created a small sample works to prove the issue. Do try create a horizontal layout with text gravity center, and animateLayouChange true. You should see this happen.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce, works completely smooth on my OnePlus One

Comment: Tested on Nexus 6 Mashmallow, issue replicated. I provide a git repository of the code https://github.com/elye/issue_horizontal_layout_animate. Do get it and run.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Support Transitions instead `animateLayoutChanges`

First, remove `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` from your XML file

After, add `compile 'com.android.support:transition:25.4.0'` to your app dependencies.

Then, add this line before change visibility (TransitionManager from android.support.transition package)

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parentOfAnimatedView);
```

For your code

```
public void clickMe(View view) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) billionText.getParent());
        if (billionText.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            billionText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            billionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem. The "Hundreds" still jump. Try on landscape mode, the jump is more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `animateLayoutChanges` only affects subclasses of `ViewGroup`. `TextView` can't react to layout change animations, so the text jumps. There are two ways to fix it:

1) Wrap each `TextView` in a `FrameLayout` and put the weight on the `FrameLayout`. You'll also have to add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to each, as well as calling `getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)` on each `FrameLayout`. This is kind of gross layout-wise, but it will allow you to keep using the transition animations.

2) Use a `ValueAnimator` and animate the weight of the (dis)appearing item. The animation may be a little choppier since it needs to lay out the `LinearLayout` on each frame, but it should still be passable. You'd also have to solve for text reflowing on the disappearing item, maybe by animating it fading out first and then animating the weight change.